# Regex match reverse

Tags: regex, ansible

I have a string

```yaml
  string: Octane_2022.1.0.6_Houdini_19.5.493_OSX.zip
```

and regex currently

```yaml
  regex_search('[0-9]{2}.[0-9]')
```

This will get 2022. The expected result is `19.5` whatever is in that field.

Essentially, I need to always gather the base version number of this installer. It works fine when there is no year in there, but how do I force my regex to only get it if it is 2 digits + "." + 1 digit?

Comment: Please define the constants in your string. What part of the string do we always know will be the same, and what parts are dynamic?

Comment: To match a dot you have to escape it `\.` Otherwise, a dot `.` matches any character. This is the reason why your regex `[0-9]{2}.[0-9]` matches `2022`.

Comment: (To those who asked to close). It can be expected that the parts of the string (filename) are separated by the underscore `'_'`. We are looking for the `2 digits + "." + 1 digit` part. What other details or clarity do you need?

Comment: Thanks for this Vladimir -- for some reason when attempting to do it with \. it gave me an error with ansible which I couldn't get around.  It was saying there is a syntax error:
`Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  found unknown escape character`

Comment: See the difference between [7.3.1. Double-Quoted Style](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#731-double-quoted-style) and [7.3.2. Single-Quoted Style](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#732-single-quoted-style). In a double-quoted string, the backslash  \  must be escaped `" \\. "` even when single-quoted inside an argument `"regex_search('[0-9]{2}\\.[0-9]')"`. No escape is needed when single-quoted `regex: '[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]'`. This is the main reason for putting a regex into a separate variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the variables

```yaml
  version_regex: '^\d{2}\.\d{1}.*$'
  version: "{{ string|
               split('_')|
               select('regex', version_regex)|first }}"
  major: "{{ version|split('.')|first }}"
  major_minor: "{{ version|splitext|first }}"
  patch: "{{ version|split('.')|last }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  version: 19.5.493
  major: 19
  major_minor: 19.5
  patch: 493
```

---

Details:

Given the string

```yaml
  string: Octane_2022.1.0.6_Houdini_19.5.493_OSX.zip
```

Split the string

```yaml
  arr: "{{ string|split('_') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  arr:
  - Octane
  - 2022.1.0.6
  - Houdini
  - 19.5.493
  - OSX.zip
```

Select the item that *"is 2 digits + '.' + 1 digit"*

```yaml
  version: "{{ arr|select('regex', version_regex)|first }}"
  version_regex: '^\d{2}\.\d{1}.*$'
```

gives

```yaml
  version: 19.5.493
```

If the version's format is semantic versioning (major.minor.patch) split the items

```yaml
  major: "{{ version|split('.')|first }}"
  major_minor: "{{ version|splitext|first }}"
  patch: "{{ version|split('.')|last }}"
```

gives

```yaml
    major: 19
    major_minor: 19.5
    patch: 493
```

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    string: Octane_2022.1.0.6_Houdini_19.5.493_OSX.zip
    arr: "{{ string|split('_') }}"
    version_regex: '^\d{2}\.\d{1}.*$'
    # version: "{{ arr|select('regex', version_regex)|first }}"
    version: "{{ string|
                 split('_')|
                 select('regex', version_regex)|first }}"
    major: "{{ version|split('.')|first }}"
    major_minor: "{{ version|splitext|first }}"
    patch: "{{ version|split('.')|last }}"
    # major_minor: "{{ version|split('.')[:2]|join('.') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: arr
    - debug:
        var: version

    - debug:
        msg: |
          major: {{ major }}
          major_minor: {{ major_minor }}
          patch: {{ patch }}
```

Comment: This is a great comment! Thank you for explaining this in such a way.  I didn't even think to just use split & jinja in separate variables! That is such a good idea.  Then I don't have to clutter all of my code with this stuff

Answer (score 1):

you can use this regex

```
Octane_(.*(?=\_Houdini))_Houdini_(.*(?=\_))
```

it will return 2 groups of value

- year: `2022.1.0.6`
- version: `19.5.493`

how this regex works

```
(?=\_)
```

using positive lookahead to match the indentifier you want, for this case is `_Houdini` for 1st group and `_` for 2nd group

Answer (score 1):

We can work backwards by using a lookahead:

```
(?<=_)\d{2}\.\d(?=\.\d+_[A-Z]+\.zip)
```

This only matches if preceded by an underscore, then looks for exactly two digits followed by a `"."`, then by one digit, and it is only matched if proceeded by another dot, one or more digits, an underscore, several capital letters, then the literal `".zip"`.

[Try it](https://regex101.com/r/m4NW2r/1).